# Rails connect application with users own external data base

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I am working in the application where i am using PostgreSQL as database .I want to to provide choice to user either use application internal database or user can connect with his own external database in the application.

If user choose application internal database all the user's related stuff will be get saved in the application's internal database and if user connects with his own database then application have to use users database for this user.

How this can be achieved in rails.

Comment: When you say "own external database", do you mean one controlled by the user on a separate server to the application or do you intend to create a database for the user on your own server?

Comment: I mean to say database created at users own server on a separate server.

Comment: With multiple users?  So the application could end up connecting to many different databases?

Comment: Yes for multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, though I would steer clear of ORMs like ActiveRecord which mandate their own conventions and provide limited SQL features.

Since it sounds like you want to connect to arbitrary databases you can't use regular models anyway.

The best known data access layer and DB utility knife for ruby,  and one which I use in my ruby projects is Sequel.

Sequel provides full capability to express complex queries and works with quite a number of DBs.

Above all read the documentation and determine for yourself if it meets your specific requirements.